# Git Error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am trying to merge in git and get the following error:

```
"error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/.DS_Store
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that's a special OS X file to do fancy things when displaying the folder.

I think you just need to edit your .gitignore file (in the root directory of your application) to include that file and then try again.

**EDIT:** You may also have to use git rm app/.DS_Store if it's already tracking the file (I think I've had to do that in the past with this sort of problem).

Answer (score 0):

`.DS_Store` files are special files for OS/X and you do not want them inside your git repo.

If you don't already have one, create a `.gitignore` file in the root of your source tree and add the line `.DS_Store` into it.

Here are some common things to have in your `.gitignore` file for a Rails app.

```
.DS_Store
log/*.log
tmp/**/*
db/*.sqlite3
public/system/**/*
```

Comment: Did you try using git rm to remove it as I suggested in my answer?